# how to load adds in android?

Tags: android

I loaded adds from  AdMob creating a site on AdMob. For that I needed the Publisher ID of the site that I created. But at there(manage settings of the site) I can only change the colors of the add.

I have created an add and have sent for approval (campaign--> add group--> add). But how can I use this add after approval?  How can assign this add to my site?

Or is there any way to load the add in my android app with out creating a site?

Answer (score 0):

You want add a campaign for your product or get ads in your application to get money?

Comment: add a campaign for your product

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your ads on your own app. I suggest you to use "House Ads" feature on AdMob. You can find it on Sites & Apps --> House Ads

Comment: You need to enable House Ads for you app. Go to Sites & Apps page and look at your app entry, there is a word "Off" in the House Ads column. You need to hover your cursor on the word "Off" and there will be "Edit" button appears.